# Why ARP request is unicast?

Tags: tcpip, arp, unicast

I have a wireshark capture that indicating a unicast ARP request from source to destination.

[image: Wireshark screenshot]

As per my understanding ARP requests (including gratutious ARP) use broadcast. 
In what case the unicast ARP request is used ?

Comment: Can you show the dump of the packet? Could this be a DHCPINFORM packet?

Comment: @ott The link (wireshark capture PNG Image) I mentioned above includes the dump of the packet I am talking about

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [RFC1122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1122.txt), section 2.3.2.1  - ARP Cache Validation:

> **IMPLEMENTATION:** Four mechanisms have been used, sometimes in
>   combination, to flush out-of-date cache entries.
>
> [...]
>
> **(2) Unicast Poll** -- Actively poll the remote host by   periodically
>   sending a point-to-point ARP Request   to it, and delete the entry if
>   no ARP Reply is   received from N successive polls. Again, the
>   timeout should be on the order of a minute, and typically N is 2.

Also, [`arping`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/arping) is using unicast ARP requests to reduce the amount of broadcast traffic.